# Drag Vertices of mesh with mouse unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I want to do something like this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioiaDXOI6zI

I want to be able to deform mesh and change shape just like that video with mouse or keyboard input. I am looking for a light way to do this work because every time I change vertices a new mesh is created which is very heavy in terms of performance. I also want to compare two meshes if they are alike or not but I am stuck at this, would appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks

**This is my code so far:**

```c#
public class MeshDeformation: MonoBehaviour {

   MeshFilter mf;
   Vector3[] verts;

   public Vector3 value = new Vector3(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f);

   void Start () {
       mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
       verts = mf.mesh.vertices;
       Debug.Log("Vertices" + verts.Length);
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {
       if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
       {
           RaycastHit hit;
           Vector3 input = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
           Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

           if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, 300))
           {
               Vector3 hitVertices = FindNearestPoint(hit.point);
               RaisePoint(hitVertices,value);
               Debug.Log("coming inside");
           }
       }
   }
   private Vector3 FindNearestPoint(Vector3 point)
   {
       Vector3 NearestPoint = new Vector3();
       float lastDistance = 99999999f;

       for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++)
       {
           float distance = GetDistance(point, verts[i]);
           if (distance < lastDistance)
           {
               lastDistance = distance;
               NearestPoint = verts[i];
           }
       }
       return NearestPoint;
   }

   private float GetDistance(Vector3 start, Vector3 end)
   {
       return Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow((start.x - end.x), 2) + Mathf.Pow((start.y - end.y), 2) + Mathf.Pow((start.z - end.z), 2));
   }

   private void RaisePoint(Vector3 point, Vector3 val)
   {
       int index = -1;
       for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++)
       {
           if (verts[i] == point)
           {
               index = i;
               break;
           }
       }

       if (index == -1)
       {
           Debug.LogError("Could not match points");
       }
       else 
       {
           Vector3 newPoint = verts[index];
           newPoint += val;
           verts[index] = newPoint;
          // mf.mesh.Clear();
           mf.mesh.vertices = verts;
           mf.mesh.RecalculateNormals();
           mf.mesh.RecalculateBounds(); 
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to do Scenario 2 as seen in the [Mesh documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html):

> 2. Modifying vertex attributes every frame:
>      a) get vertices
>      b) modify them
>      c) assign them back to the mesh.

So you don't want that `Clear()` call at all (you have it commented out right now, but it's unneeded and only included in Scenario 3).

Similarly `RecalculateNormals()` and `RecalculateBounds()` are probably pretty intensive. You might want to delay performing these operations until the user has released the mouse button. The mesh would have improper shadows during the modification, but this is probably an acceptable loss.

Otherwise your code looks pretty close to the example in the documenation.

Note also that Debug.Log(...) introduces a fair amount of overhead and calling it every frame may be slowing things down as well. Try commenting those out and see if your performance issues go away, as well as comparing with also removing the recalculate commands.

Comment: Thanks for sharing information. What I really want is to click on the mesh and drag those vertices where I clicked in direction of wherever mouse goes. I have tried adding mouse position to the nearest vertices where the ray is cast but it's not working. Can you please guide?

Comment: @imrankhan That sounds like a new question. I don't have any insight in any case.